# Flash MP3 Player and php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, flash

I;m using a player called Flash Mp3 Player, this works ok when i hardcode the mp3 file into the . But im reading from a db, and when i switch the hardcoded file for the variable that holds the data from the row nothing happens?

This code works as the mp3 file is hardcoded

```
echo '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player_mp3_maxi.swf" width="25" 
              height="20">
<param name="movie" value="player_mp3_maxi.swf" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="mp3=/soundclips/wheelsforwing.mp3&amp;
showslider=0&amp;width=25&amp;bgcolor1=189ca8&amp;bgcolor2=085c68" />
</object>'
```

this code does not work, i replaced the hardcoded filename with a variable

```
echo '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player_mp3_maxi.swf" width="25" 
              height="20">
<param name="movie" value="player_mp3_maxi.swf" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="mp3=$soundfile&amp;showslider=0&amp;
             width=25&amp;bgcolor1=189ca8&amp;bgcolor2=085c68" />
</object>'
```

$soundfile holds a path to wheelsforwing.mp3

Can  anyone help?

Comment: Use <?php echo $variable ?> to display your variable into html... or else it will just be displayed as $soundfile in HTML xD

Comment: question edited to show echos now, i forgot to copy paste them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're not showing a PHP `echo` or `HEREDOC` containing that string, you cannot simply stuff a PHP variable into the middle of some html plain text. You'd be sending the literal characters `$`, `s`, `o`, etc... to the client, not the contents of the variable.

perhaps you need

```
<param ...... value="mp3=<?php echo $soundfile ?>.... />
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- note this
```

instead.

Comment: i forgot to copy the echos just, question edited to show them!

Comment: Then you're using the wrong quotes. Strings with `'`-quotes do **NOT** replace variable values, and you're sending a literal `$`, `s`, etc... to the client. Use `"` quotes instead.

Comment: also the & can be a problem ... I recommend just putting the dynamic data inside the <?php ?> tags. It helps readability also

Comment: @MarcB Thank you so much, works now! I will remember this next time!